# Downloaded the jQuery (from its website) library to run it offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a fade in animation of my picture when the mouse enters to it. but the animation does not work

So I downloaded the jQuery.min.js ( specifically jquery-2.1.4.min.js but i renamed it to jquery.min.js ) file from jQuery site and I linked it to my html file

just like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** it is not in a separated folder. they are in the same location with the html file

I also linked my jQuery animations from my html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="animations.js"></script>
```

**Note:** it is not also in a separated folder. they are in the same location with the html file

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.profile-image').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', 1)
    });
});
```

This is my html and css code:

```
<div id="profile_container">
   <section class="profile_pic">
  <img src="profile1.jpg" class="profile-image" style="border-radius: 50px/15px; width:100%; border: 3px solid white; display: none;  ">
    </section>
</div>
```

I think my codes do not have any errors. Still, it does not work when i hover my cursor in to it or the mouse enters into it. It does not fade in.

Comment: How do you mouse into something that is not rendered?

Comment: what? i dont get you

Comment: Your image is set to `display: none` it will not be rendered, and the `mouseenter` event can never be fired. Use `opacity` or maybe `visibility` to hide and show your image.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the event on the `section` instead of the `img` so there's actually something to mouse over in the DOM.

In my snippet, I also set the section element to the dimensions of the image, and I used `.hover()` instead of `.mouseenter()` so I could easily make it fade back out on `.mouseleave()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.profile_pic').hover(
    function() {
      $('img.profile-image').fadeIn('slow')
    },
    function() {
      $('img.profile-image').fadeOut('slow')
    });
});
```

```css
.profile-image {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="profile_container">
  <section class="profile_pic" style="height:131px;width:506px;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png" class="profile-image">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaxZoom Your edit is being discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306697/are-there-guidelines-for-what-should-should-not-be-edited?cb=1), where the current consensus is that is a bit too much for an edit - in general, you should comment to point out inaccuracies and/or post a separate answer instead of editing an existing post too much, and do make use of the Edit Summary to justify non-trivial edits.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0`, not `display: none;`

```
.profile-image{
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By your code I think you want to **fadeOut** the image / fadeIn will bring it back when is faded out....

In that case, just do this

```
$('.profile-image').mouseenter(function(){
      $(".profile-image").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

If your image is faded use **fadeIn**